# Undoing last save in Breeze

Tags: breeze

I am aware that it is a weird approach but I have to create and save a 'parent' entity before I can add children. The problem I am having now is that if the user decides to stop creating the new children the parent is still created.

So my question is: Is it possible to undo the last save in Breeze? Another option is deleting the saved items based on their IDs from the `result.entities` that's generated after the save but that would be very cumbersome.

(If its any help, I'm using AngularJS)

Comment: Can you create (but not save) the parent on the client, then create the children, then save the whole thing when the user is finished?

Comment: @SteveSchmitt I tried, but I need the parent to have an ID before the children are saved because else their ParentID property will be a negative value that doesn't correspond with the parents ID anymore. (Also I dont want to link them as a Foreign Key)

Comment: Yes, it has to be a FK for Breeze to fix up the relationship automatically.  You can declare ParentID to be a FK on the client, even though it not an FK on the server.  Then you could do a single save from the client, but have it do your 2-step save (parent, then child) on the server.